# MS Access - VBA to add data in all tables

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, vba, insert-into

I have 68 tables in my database and what I want is to add data to all these tables with just one click.

The purpose of the database is to determine in which position a specific player is more proficient; so I have a table (tblMain) which contains all the attributes (Pace, Acceleration, Dribbling, etc) and the remaining 67 tables have only specific attributes (Pace & Dribbling - tblPosition1).

What I want to achieve is: user will add all the player attributes and then click on Save - upon clicking on save, all the attributes will be inserted into tblMain and on the other tables only the relevant attributes (i.e. for tblPosition1 I only want to add Pace and Dribbling).

I can achieve this by having 68 different INSERT INTO statements but I am looking for a more quicker way if you have any suggestion.

EDIT: for a better understanding:

This is the table for the roles

```
Attributes      Role1      Role2     ...     Role68
___________________________________________________
Attr1           Primary    Secondary ...     
Attr2                      Primary   ...     Primary
  .
  .
  .
Attr36          Primary              ...     Secondary
```

This is the tables with athletes' data

```
Attributes      Athlete1   Athlete2   ...    Atlhete7
_____________________________________________________
Attr1           4          2          ...    5
Attr2           8          4          ...    1
  .
  .
  .
Attr36          2          3          ...    6
```

What I want now is for each Role the average of the (Primary attributes * 0.7) + average of (Secondary attributes * 0.2) + average of (remaining attributes * 0.1).

I know that's not possible with only 1 SQL but the problem is that even with more complex things I am not able to find a solution.

Comment: It's impossible to insert data to more than one table using single SQL query. You will need to create VBA code, which creates SQL statements for each table, it should be easy. And I suspect the database structure may be improved. 67 tables for simple database is too much. Also storing the same information in more than one place may affect data integrity

Comment: Yeah, I know @Sergey S. it's a big mess. I am trying to streamline it as we speak :) however do you think I can write in all those tables by using a loop through the tables?

Comment: I would create new table with required metadata: table name, column name to update and source data name. Then just cycle thru this table, create SQL for each table and execute it

Comment: I think you need only one table and 67 queries.

Comment: I'll try to explain a bit better now. For each athlete I have 36 attributes and 68 different positions where the athlete can cover. For each of these positions, some attributes are considered of primary importance, others of secondary importance and the remaining of no importance. I want to assess each athlete against those primary and secondary attributes to see where he/she is best at. Before I had 68 different tables for each available position, now I have 1 table with the 36 attributes as header and 1 last column with a list of all the positions.

Comment: I'm sorry @CMigli I think your database schema is still not optimal and I think some of the comments here have lead you down a bad path. You have three things you are trying to track. 1. Players, 2. Positions, and 3. Attributes. That's three tables. The position table would be `player | position` with multiple records for each player. The attributes table would be `player | attribute | importance`. That being said, it doesn't address your question. You are still going to need multiple insert statements (one for adding a player, and one for each attribute into the attribute table).

Comment: As for your single table schema like you have it now, you will need to write the sql statement dynamically in VBA since you have a column for each attribute and then execute the dynamically created statement. This is why such a schema is not optimal. Also if you want to add attributes, it means you have to alter the table. In short, if you find that Dynamically written SQL (where you have to, in code, change the table or column names in your statement) or you must often alter the table or schema, then you are probably headed down the wrong path.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @JNevill, I have edited my first post with a mock up of the data I've got. The problem with your suggestion is that the importance of the attribute depends on the position and not on the player nor the attribute itself therefore the "AttributesTable" as suggested is not feasible.

Comment: I see. So perhaps an attributes table like `person | position | attribute` and a person_position table like `person | position` and a attribute_position table like 'position | attribute | important` and then a position table to hold info about the position that hasn't been discussed here yet like `position | name_of_position | other_attribute`

Comment: At any rate, the idea is that you add rows, not fields or tables as new positions, attributes, players, and relationships between those come into your database. Also that your sql takes the form `INSERT INTO mytable (column1, column2, column3) VALUES (variable1, variable2, variable3...)` and not `INSERT INTO variableTable (<some variable list of coumns>) VALUES (variable2, variable3, variable4)` because this will get out of hand quickly (although sometimes its necessary as a last resort).

Comment: @JNevill unfortunately the schema you are proposing doesn't match the structure of the data I have. For example the table attribute_position would be a big mess because for each position I have to list all the attributes therefore I would have the same position listed 36 times (once per each attribute). Also the table attribute makes little sense because the aim of this project is to find the best position for each player hence having a position field is pointless as much as it is the person_position table. Unless I am missing something very obvious.

Comment: @SergeyS. 67 tables is normal. I have many production applications with that many tables. As long as they are properly normalized it's all good.